# What did Moses possess that caused the Jews to make the Golden Calf?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> וַיֹּאמְר֤וּ אֵלָיו֙ ק֣וּם ׀ עֲשֵׂה־לָ֣נוּ אֱלֹהִ֗ים אֲשֶׁ֤ר יֵֽלְכוּ֙
> לְפָנֵ֔ינוּ כִּי־זֶ֣ה ׀ מֹשֶׁ֣ה הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר הֶֽעֱלָ֙נוּ֙ מֵאֶ֣רֶץ
> מִצְרַ֔יִם לֹ֥א יָדַ֖עְנוּ מֶה־הָ֥יָה לֽוֹ׃
>
> They said to Aaron, "Arise and make us a god, because this man, Moses,
> whom we raised from Egypt, we don't know what he had."

It seems that Moses may have possessed something that he never told the people about. That lack of knowledge caused them to ask Aaron to make a Golden Calf. What was it that Moses possessed, and why did he hide this info from everyone?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).